# Am I able to use a php script called from an href tag to trigger a jQuery event?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, header, download

I have a single php script on my site that facilitates my site's downloads (logs user info, controls user permissions etc). A typical link looks like this on my site:

```
<a href="file_download.php?file_id=12345">Download file 12345</a>
```

In **file_download.php** I check to make sure the file request is valid, and if so, it does a header force file download

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
```

which forces the download prompt in the user's browser. The user never leaves the page they click the link on.

What I am wondering is if I am able to toggle a jQuery event from file_download.php onto the parent page? It seems if I do anything on file_download.php other than a 'header force download' the user will leave the page.

Ideally I would like to keep my href links unchanged (for the sake of not editing a million instances site wide) and have file_download.php toggle a lightbox window prompting for user information before the download (if needed of course).

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to toggle the event from the PHP page, you could attach the information box to all of your download links, and then use JavaScript to redirect:

```
var downloadLink;

$(".download-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    downloadLink= $(this).attr("href");
    displayLightbox();
});

$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //form validation
    if(formValidated = true){
        window.location = downloadLink;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I was thinking of how to do this all wrong. I'm now on the right track thanks to the power of jQuery and your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PAL2p/2/) like the above one.

This is your link :

```
<a id="downloadLinkId" href="file_download.php?file_id=12345">Download file 12345</a>
```

And this is your javascript:

```
$("#downloadLinkId").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    launchLightBoxWindow();
});
```

Rest of the code is on jsfiddle.